# Describe runtime errors using Composable, app crash with sig: 9

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-jetpack-compose, native

How to show stacktrack, mininum debug data, if an error happens on Android Composable using Kotlin ?

I simulate a runtime erro by dividing a number by 0, and the app just close and show no stacktrace. It just show a message `Sending signal. PID: 28593 SIG: 9`

**MainActivity.kt** - the only file in project, I'm omit imports

```kotlin
package com.alexaleluia12.appdado

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            AppDadoTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    val mydice = Dice()
    var currentValueDice by remember { mutableStateOf("-") }
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(text = currentValueDice, fontSize = 32.sp)
        Button(
            onClick = {
                var newValue = mydice.roll()
                println("novo valor Dado - $newValue")
                currentValueDice = newValue.toString()
            },

            ) {
            Text("ROLL")
        }
    }

}

class Dice(val sides: Int = 6) {

    fun roll(): Int {
        return 1 / 0
        //return (1..6).random()
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    AppDadoTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** is the same created by android studio, just define MainActivity

My local enviroment

```
Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2
Kotlin 1.7.0
compose_ui_version = 1.2.1
Running on phisical device Xaiomi android 10
```

**Print LogCat**
[image: Print logcat sig 9]

I try to use try/catch block. I expected to show any debug data if an crash happen on Composable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, Compose doesn't really have a good way to catch exceptions from async calls. You can register an uncaught exception handler to at least get them in your log:

```
fun registerExceptionHandler() {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler { _, e ->
        log.error("Uncaught exception", e)
    }
}
```